# Python: Separate two paths in one list entry

Tags: python, path, networkx

From the function `[p for p in nx.all_shortest_paths(G,i,j)]` I get all shortest paths between the nodes i , j in a list. My problem is that if there is more than one path, the list entry looks like this: `list[5] = [[1, 3, 7], [1, 5, 7]]`

I need to separate these two paths to get something like `list[5] = [1, 3, 7]` and  `list[6] = [1, 5, 7]`. I was able to get all numbers as an own entry, but that is not what I need.

Comment: Do it line by line. Do not use list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this one liner will fix it:

```
list(reduce(lambda acc, cur: acc + (cur if isinstance(cur[0], list) else [cur]), l, [] ))
```

Replace the variable `l` (second argument to `reduce`) with whatever you have called your list, and this creates a new list, leaving `l` unchanged.